# In a Warren's Abstract Machine, where are Argument Variables created?

Tags: prolog, warren-abstract-machine

I'm trying to create my own WAM implementation and I'm using the instructions in [Figure 2.10](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwambook.sourceforge.net%2Fwambook.pdf&a=bi&pagenumber=39) of "Warren's Abstract Machine: A Tutorial Reconstruction" as a test case. However, I need to pass `A1` and `A2` to `get_structure`. But where are both variables created? `put_value` and `put_variable` both create A-variables but neither is listed in the instructions.

Answer (score 3):

A<sub>i</sub> are "argument registers". They are part of the machine. So `put_value` does not create them, it fills them. Figure 2.8 on page 23 says:

```
put_value X_n, A_i ===  A_i <- X_n
```

meaning, store the value X<sub>n</sub> in A<sub>i</sub>.

Comment: The first line in Figure 2.10 is `get_structure`, it needs a register position as a second argument. However, at that time all registers are empty. My question is: which argument do I pass to `get_structure` as the second argument?

Comment: Pg. 22 says A_i are actually X_i registers.

Comment: All registers are empty, including the X register and HEAP. My question is: which register position to I pass when all registers are empty?

Comment: I would expect them not to be empty at that point. I'll check it.

Comment: That's what I would be expecting too. Maybe my problem is explained in the book but I've read chapter 2 several times and I can't figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: pg 13: *"Compiling a program term `p` is just a bit trickier, although not by much. Observe
that it assumes that a query `?-q` will have built a term on the heap and set register
`X1` to contain its address."* so when the compiled program is run, the registers won't be empty. -- The "value" you pass for `X1` depends on implementation, but 0 is a sensible value: X1 is the 1st of the X registers, and your implementation will know their base address, so it can use 0 as an offset for the 1st of them. Symbolically though, you just pass in `X1`. It's a position in itself.